# TailwindCSS set same height for Grid Card Image

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind css for responsive grid card list. Card has image and title. I can't control the image size. So height of card is not same because of some small image size. At img tag, if I gave heigh, h-46, all image are same but aspect ratio is not working.[image]

```
<div className="container mx-auto px-4 md:px-12">
  {artists && artists.length > 0 ? (
    <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-1 lg:-mx-4">
      {artists.map((artist, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={index}
            className="group my-1 px-1 w-full md:w-1/2 lg:my-4 lg:px-4 lg:w-1/5 cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() => {
              onClickHandler(slide.id);
            }}
          >
            <article className="overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg ">
              <div className="relative cursor-pointer">
                <img
                  alt="Placeholder"
                  className="block h-auto w-full"
                  src={artist.profile_picture}
                />
                <button className="absolute top-1/2 right-1/2 -mr-3 -mt-3 rounded-lg opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100">
                  <PlayIcon className="text-primary" />
                </button>
              </div>

              <header className="flex items-center justify-between leading-tight p-2 md:p-4">
                <h1 className="text-sm">{artist.name}</h1>
              </header>
            </article>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div></div>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: Could You please add link to the repo ?